# UV unwrap and Baking two Image Textures

Tags: export, texture-baking, baking, shader-nodes

I am very new to blender. I have two image textures. I want to blend both image over a surface and baked it so that I can Import it in Gazebo with all the details. I have attached the output I want and the nodes I have used to get that output. When I baked only one of the texture comes out. Any help would be appreciated. Also, how can I add roughness to the surface so that it won't lose the texture I want.

Comment: Hello could you please show more details, like show sceenshots, maybe share the object?

Comment: With a screen-grab, please show your shader-tree in the state it's in, when you attempt a bake, and the Bake settings.  A share of a  representative .blend on https://blend-exchange.com/ pasting the link into your post, would be ideal.